# how to use navigation.navigate together with render() to change tab

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have a Floating Action Button with two internal buttons, the idea is that after clicking on the first FAB (Floating Action Button) the others are displayed, what I require is that I can click on one of the buttons that was displayed and send me to the login or to another tab, page, route.

The error I have is that I don't know where I can do the "const navigation = useNavigation()" to use the navigator and send the user to another tab

i tried to use this.props, but i couldn't get it

[image: error adding const]

[image: these are the fabs]

```
  export default class FloatingButton extends React.Component {


handleSignOut = () => {
  Alert.alert("Position 1")
  authentication
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message))
}

handleSignOut2 = () =>{Alert.alert("Position 2")}

animation = new Animated.Value(0);

toggleMenu = () => {
  const toValue = this.open ? 0 : 1;
  
  Animated.spring(this.animation, {
    toValue,
    friction: 5,
    useNativeDriver: false
  }).start();

  this.open = !this.open;
  
};

render() {
  const pinStyle2 = {
    transform: [
      { scale: this.animation },
      {
        translateY: this.animation.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, -10]
        })
      }
    ]
  };

  const pinStyle = {
    transform: [
      { scale: this.animation },
      {
        translateY: this.animation.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, -20]
        })
      }
    ]
  };

  const rotation = {
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: this.animation.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: ["0deg", "45deg"]
        })
      }
    ]
  };

  const opacity = this.animation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 0, 1]
  })
  
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
      
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handleSignOut}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.button, styles.secondary, styles.menu, pinStyle, opacity]}>
          <Entypo name="add-to-list" size={24} color="white" />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handleSignOut2}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.button, styles.secondary, styles.menu, pinStyle2, opacity]}>
          <Entypo name="check" size={24} color="white" />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggleMenu}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.button, styles.menu, rotation]}>
          <AntDesign name="plus" size={24} color="white" />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the react documentation **"You can’t use Hooks inside a class component"**. (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html). And thats what you're doing `useNavigation` is a hook and you're calling it inside a class. So either

**-** Change your class into a function

**or**

**-** Find a way to express the same functionality as the useNavigation hook but in a class